# SQL Exclude Data based on Appearing outside of parameters

Tags: sql, parameters, not-exists

I'm querying a ledger table in SQL and I've set parameters for the Period of 2020.

I'd like to exclude all lines that have a reference that appears outside of 2020 so the last row of Reference B and others like it.

So for example the last row in my example table and others like it appear  in my results, I'd like to exclude all lines that have a reference that occurs outside of 2020.

| PERIOD | TYPE | REFERENCE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202011 | X | REFERENCE A | 50 |
| 202011 | X | REFERENCE A | 50 |
| 202011 | X | REFERENCE A | 50 |
| 201911 | X | REFERENCE B | 50 |
| 201911 | X | REFERENCE B | 50 |
| 201911 | X | REFERENCE B | 50 |
| **202001 | X | REFERENCE B | 50** |

I tried a NOT EXISTS but it returned nothing. I may have done it wrong, would anybody be able to advise?

I'd like a result of

| PERIOD | TYPE | REFERENCE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202011 | X | REFERENCE A | 50 |
| 202011 | X | REFERENCE A | 50 |
| 202011 | X | REFERENCE A | 50 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: NOT EXISTS can be used. Show us your attempt!

Comment: SELECT PERIOD, TYPE, REFERENCE, AMOUNT
FROM LEDGER
WHERE PERIOD BETWEEN 202001 AND 202012 
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT REFERENCE
FROM LEDGER 
WHERE PERIOD <2020001) This was my attempt and I received no results

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: BTW, you need a _correlated_ subquery,i.e. with a condition referencing the outer table.

Comment: Ok Thanks. And I'll bear that in mind regarding editing question!

Comment: What about `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS`? `... reference NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT reference ...`

Comment: Thanks so much! It looks to be working